# Remove S-Controls from the org

Tags: s-control

I am having a list of S-Controls which I want to remove from the org. What is best way to find where a S-Control has been used in the org.

Comment: Grab all the relevant metadata and grep?

Comment: I think when you try to delete a component it shows all dependencies.